# TFS Release Powershell task to deploy to Sharepoint: "Cannot bind argument to parameter 'String' because it is null."

Tags: sharepoint, azure-devops

**Edit:**

I managed to get it to accept 1 parameter. Apparently it hates accepting 2. Now I've got another exception: remote server returning 401 unauthorized. I guess the solution for this is to not use more than 1 parameter, but that's not really a solution. Sounds like a bug to me.

---

**Original question:**

I'm at my wit's end on this one.

I have a powershell script that I'd like to execute during a Release that uploads an archived copy of the build to a document library in SharePoint. The build server that hosts TFS 2017 is running Powershell 4. When I RDP in and run the below script in ISE on the same server (precisely where TFS appears to be executing things in the tasks), it works, provided that I add the environment variables where they are commented in the script below.

When I run the same exact script (I'm running it from the drop folder) via TFS, it produces the error:

```
2017-10-17T13:48:52.5561597Z D:\BuildAgentWorkFolder\f00869677\Git\drop\publish_to_sharepoint.ps1 D:\Integration_20171017.2.zip Integration_20171017.2
2017-10-17T13:48:53.0241597Z Connecting to http://sharepoint_server/sites/TFS_DefaultCollection/NET as srv_promote...
2017-10-17T13:48:53.2737597Z ##[error]D:\BuildAgentWorkFolder\f00869677\Git\drop\publish_to_sharepoin
2017-10-17T13:48:53.2737597Z ##[error]t.ps1 : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'String' because it is null.
```

which is crazy, because you can clearly see the non-null arguments in the line executing the script.

I have tried specifying the type in the `param` section, like `[string]$filePathToUpload`. I have tried specifying the parameters in the command line arguments list, like `.\publish_to_sharepoint.ps1 -filePathToUpload "..." -fileName "..."`, both with and without quotation marks.

One thing to note is when I try to run the task with an *in-line* powershell script-- because of the character limit, I can only paste up to the first "Write-Host" line-- it passes the parameter step without error and the release passes.

Is this a bug with TFS Powershell task? I can't wrap my head around where this error is coming from.

Thanks in advance. Below are the relevant details.

---

**Powershell script:**

```
param(
    $filePathToUpload, 
    $fileName
)

#$Env:SharePointDomain = "..."
#$Env:SharePointBaseUrl = "http://sharepoint_server"
#$Env:SharePointSite = "/sites/TFS_DefaultCollection/NET/"
#$Env:SharePointUsername = "username"
#$Env:SharePointPassword = "password"
#$Env:SharePointLibrary = "library_name"

Add-Type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c, processorArchitecture=MSIL"
Add-Type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c, processorArchitecture=MSIL"

Write-Host 'Connecting to'$Env:SharePointBaseUrl$Env:SharePointSite' as '$Env:SharePointUsername'...'

try{
    $sharepointFullUrl = $Env:SharePointBaseUrl + $Env:SharePointSite

    $clientContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext $sharepointFullUrl
    $clientContext.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential $Env:SharePointUsername, (ConvertTo-SecureString $Env:SharePointPassword -AsPlainText -Force)
    $web = $clientContext.Web
    $clientContext.Load($web) 
    $clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    $relDestFilePath = $Env:SharePointSite + $Env:SharePointLibrary + "/" + $fileName

    $fStream = New-Object IO.FileStream $filePathToUpload ,'Open','Read','Read'
    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File]::SaveBinaryDirect($clientContext, $relDestFilePath, $fStream, $true)

    Write-Host 'Successfully uploaded'$fileName' to SharePoint document library '$Env:SharePointLibrary'.'
}
catch {
    Write-Error $_
}
```

**Release Task Detail:**

[image]

**Release Environment Variables:**

[image]

**Powershell Task Log**

```
2017-10-17T13:48:52.5405597Z . 'D:\BuildAgentWorkFolder\f00869677\Git\drop\publish_to_sharepoint.ps1' D:\Integration_20171017.2.zip Integration_20171017.2
2017-10-17T13:48:52.5561597Z C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "$env:PSModulePath= $env:PSModulePath + ';' + $([system.io.path]::combine($env:AGENT_HOMEDIRECTORY, 'agent\worker\modules')); try { [System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData] | Out-Null } catch { Write-Verbose 'Adding assemly: System.Security' ; Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.Security' ; [System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData] | Out-Null } ; Invoke-Expression -Command ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData]::Unprotect([System.Convert]::FromBase64String('AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE/Cl+sAmMDwyguygfTgNLUK3BteusFUlUwAAAAACAAAAAAADZgAAwAAAABAAAACMb/7FzkttmPEf8rMCA10mAAAAAASAAACgAAAAEAAAAN7Pqk+I01BNW4lONiyiuhArrpBqYAAiGrvCfLy/fPm3YiAEuhiuhKwcUEIZFza2IcrqjhKCe4Qn8qRcPMfDEiw82ZUKdNYCrzUjayfThC97Vm3/lNgP15sgTr0NpJwsfvs7fz6zG3zwqwNeu4ivYzcYI/bYd+y608v+jh3d+8vzeQgyIGhto+9WcJlIaCnYv5qymVD7nTME8pnYz+DfNkP02s50jkCySimKgVHGIUAAAAkXCoQxu5+9njKHMCkhB2FSpdivg='), [System.Convert]::FromBase64String('McDlBBSayxJHIwJ35ERNNQ=='), [System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope]::CurrentUser))) ; if (!(Test-Path -LiteralPath variable:\LastExitCode)) { Write-Verbose 'Last exit code is not set.' } else { Write-Verbose ('$LastExitCode: {0}' -f $LastExitCode) ; exit $LastExitCode }"
2017-10-17T13:48:52.5561597Z Executing the following powershell script. (workingFolder = D:\BuildAgentWorkFolder\f00869677)
2017-10-17T13:48:52.5561597Z D:\BuildAgentWorkFolder\f00869677\Git\drop\publish_to_sharepoint.ps1 D:\Integration_20171017.2.zip Integration_20171017.2
2017-10-17T13:48:53.0241597Z Connecting to http://sharepoint_server/sites/TFS_DefaultCollection/NET as srv_promote...
2017-10-17T13:48:53.2737597Z ##[error]D:\BuildAgentWorkFolder\f00869677\Git\drop\publish_to_sharepoin
2017-10-17T13:48:53.2737597Z ##[error]t.ps1 : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'String' because it is null.
2017-10-17T13:48:53.2737597Z ##[error]At line:1 char:1
2017-10-17T13:48:53.2737597Z ##[error]+ . 
2017-10-17T13:48:53.2737597Z ##[error]'D:\BuildAgentWorkFolder\f00869677\Git\drop\publish_to_sharepo 
2017-10-17T13:48:53.2737597Z ##[error]...
2017-10-17T13:48:53.2737597Z ##[error]+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2017-10-17T13:48:53.2737597Z ##[error]~~~
2017-10-17T13:48:53.2737597Z ##[error]    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorExcep 
2017-10-17T13:48:53.2737597Z ##[error]   tion
2017-10-17T13:48:53.2737597Z ##[error]    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorExceptio 
2017-10-17T13:48:53.2737597Z ##[error]   n,publish_to_sharepoint.ps1
2017-10-17T13:48:53.2737597Z ##[error] 
2017-10-17T13:48:53.2737597Z ##[error]Process completed with exit code 0 and had 1 error(s) written to the error stream.
```

Comment: Regarding update, what’s the updated script or you just pass an argument in PowerShell task? Does SharePointPassword variable is still a secured variable? On the other hand, add System.Debug variable with true value, then start release and post the detail log here.

Comment: Do you solve this issue? Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive?

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue: `$Env:SharePointPassword`. Secrets aren't stored as environment variables. Modify your script and pass in the password as a parameter.

Comment: Thank you, but that's not it; I should have edited my original question. While not ideal, that variable is not marked as secret. At one point that was being passed in as a variable, but I had another unsolvable problem with passing in more than one parameter. So that isn't my solution. You're right, though.